# ASPx Inline Expressing <%= %> equates at runtime to %3c%25=

Tags: c#, asp.net, inline

I have a solution with a couple of projects. Both use inline expression syntax, such as:

```
<p><a runat="server" href="<%=MyProject.Global.PathSite %>">My Link</a></p>
```

Assuming that MyProject.Global.PathSite equates to

```
public const String Whatever = @"http://www.myurl.com/";
```

At both design time and at runtime project A, the first project that I created in the solution, evaluates the expression correctly, while project B, the second project that I created a couple of months later, evaluates the expression as

```
%3c%25=MyProject.Global.PathSite%20%25%3e
```

Basically, ASP.Net treads <% %> as HTML text rather than a tag that it should process, while the second one does not.

Any thoughts?

UPDATE:
I reworked the wording of the question to better make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After suffering with this issue for a couple of weeks, I finally figured out the problem.

The problem is that you cannot use <% %> in any tag, where the runat attribute is server. You can use <% %> on client side tags only.

For tags that are runat server, then simply go to the Page_Load event and enter the property through the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting  <%=MyProjectName.ClassName.PublicProperty %> in a literal with runar=server, you could do that with both in fact.

Comment: I added the actual line. The syntax runat=server, is there.